# Need to use apply or broadcasting and masking to iterate over a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply, array-broadcasting

I have a data frame that I need to iterate over. I want to use either apply or broadcasting and masking. This is the pseudocode I am trying to improve upon.

2 The algorithm
Algorithm 1: The algorithm
*initialize* the population (of size n) uniformly randomly, obeying the bounds;
**while** *a pre-determined number of iterations is not complete* **do**
*set the random parameters (two independent parameters for each of the d
variables); find the best and the worst vectors in the population;*
**for** each vector in the population **do** create a new vector using the
current vector, the best vector, the worst vector, and the random
parameters;
if the new vector is at least as good as the current vector then
current vector = new vector;

This is the code I have so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-5.0, 10.0, size = (20, 5)), columns = list('ABCDE'))
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df

#while portion of pseudocode
f_func = np.square(df).sum(axis=1)
final_func = np.square(f_func)
xti_best = final_func.idxmin()
xti_worst = final_func.idxmax()
print(final_func)
print(df.head())
print(df.tail())

*#for loop of pseudocode
#for row in df.iterrows():
#implement equation from assignment
#define in array math
#xi_new = row.to_numpy() + np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (1, 5)) * (df.iloc[xti_best].values - np.absolute(row.to_numpy())) - np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (1, 5)) * (df.iloc[xti_worst].values - np.absolute(row.to_numpy()))
#print(xi_new)*
  

    df2 = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row == 0 else row + np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (1, 5)) * (df.iloc[xti_best].values - np.absolute(axis = 1)))
    print(df2)
```

The formula I am trying to use for xi_new is:

#xi_new = xi_current + random value between 0,1(xti_best -abs(xi_current)) - random value(xti_worst - abs(xi_current))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm implementing your formula correctly, but hopefully this helps

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-5.0, 10.0, size = (20, 5)), columns = list('ABCDE'))

#while portion of pseudocode
f_func = np.square(df).sum(axis=1)
final_func = np.square(f_func)
xti_best_idx = final_func.idxmin()
xti_worst_idx = final_func.idxmax()

xti_best = df.loc[xti_best_idx]
xti_worst = df.loc[xti_worst_idx]

#Calculate random values for the whole df for the two different areas where you need randomness
nrows,ncols = df.shape
r1 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (nrows, ncols))
r2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size = (nrows, ncols))

#xi_new = xi_current + random value between 0,1(xti_best -abs(xi_current)) - random value(xti_worst - abs(xi_current))
df= df+r1*xti_best.sub(df.abs())-r2*xti_worst.sub(df.abs())

df
```